# MYSQL MATCH...AGAINST returning no results

Tags: mysql

I am completely baffled by this one.

I am currently working on an ecommerce website, and have a table full of test products. In this table is a field called 'name' which is of type TEXT and has a FULLTEXT index.

I inserted a few hundred rows of dummy data, every single row was inserted with "test product" (without the quotes) as it's value in the 'name' field.

However, running the following command returns zero results, even though the word 'product' is currently in the name field for every row.

SELECT name FROM Products
WHERE MATCH (name) AGAINST ('product')

I have checked the server variables, everything is set to the default values. The min characters are 4, stopwords are default etc. As far as I can tell, product is not a stopword.

If there is any further information that I can provide that might help to find the resolution to this problem let me know.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: `SELECT name FROM Products WHERE name LIKE '%product%'` ?

Comment: I think a string which is common to all the rows is considered to be "too common" and hence, ignored.

Comment: The reason I am using MATCH...AGAINST is so that I can build a robust search engine, searching both the name and description of each product, ultimatly so that i can order them by the most relevant.

LIKE does not achieve anywhere near the same results, as it does not order the results based on how close the match is, it simply returns everything with equal relevance.

Thanks for the response though!

Answer (score 8):

From [MySQL documentation on Fulltext searches](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-natural-language.html), your search query is considered to be triggering a stop word as the relevant string is present in all the rows.

> The 50% threshold has a significant implication when you first try
>   full-text searching to see how it works: If you create a table and
>   insert only one or two rows of text into it, every word in the text
>   occurs in at least 50% of the rows. As a result, no search returns any
>   results. Be sure to insert at least three rows, and preferably many
>   more. Users who need to bypass the 50% limitation can use the boolean
>   search mode

Here is a link to refer for [Boolean Full-Text Searches](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-boolean.html)

Comment: thanks for your quick response. This has been the answer to my problem!

It's funny, i've been using match...against for years and have never come accross this problem!

Thanks again for the help.

Comment: I had the same issue with a table having only one row (testing data).  The MATCH() AGAINST() clause returned zero results, even though the field contained the word.  After adding two more rows containing different text in each, the search works fine.  Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: Thanks a lot!! The query was not working on my dev environment with 1 or 2 rows, but was working perfectly on production.. good tip, thanks!!